# Mismatch of shapes when using advanced indexing

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I am developing a custom classifier that acts like an ensemble, combining minor classifiers together and the output of the ensemble is actually a majority voting. One important thing to mention is that every classifier has a "weight"  associated with it for each sample.

Here is the `predict` method:

```
def predict(self, X):        
    
    G = self._compute_g(X) # G comes from a softmax distribution
    pred = np.zeros( (len(self._estimators), X.shape[0]), dtype=int ) 
    
    for i, estimator in enumerate(self._estimators): #loop each minor classifier
        y_est = estimator.predict(X)    
        pred[i] = y_est

    pred = pred.T # Prediction matrix (samples x classifiers)
    C = len(self._classes) # number of classes of the dataset
    M, N = pred.shape

    row, col = np.indices((M,N))
    P3d = np.zeros(shape=(M,N,C))
    P3d[row, col, pred-1] = G
    P = P3d.sum(axis=1)
    return np.argmax(P, axis=1)
```

For the majority voting, i create a `P` matrix (samples x n_classes) that sums the classifier weights that voted in a given class. For instance: supposing we have 3 classifiers trying to predict sample `k` for a 3-class problem. Classifier weights are `[0.3, 0.4, 0.6]`, and predictions are `[1,1,2]`. The `k`-th row of matrix `P` will be `[0.7, 0.6, 0]` and the output of the ensemble classifier will be `1`.

The problem is that i am trying to use advanced indexing to build matrix `P3d` (used to build matrix `P`), and i'm getting the following error when trying to predict Iris dataset:

`ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (150,6) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (150,3)`

This error comes from this line: `P3d[row, col, pred-1] = G`, but i have no clue what's causing this issue.

**Shapes of matrices involved**

- `G`: n_samples x n_classifiers
- `pred (M,N)`: n_samples x n_classifiers
- `P`: n_samples x n_classes
- return of function (last line): n_samples x 1

Comment: Tell us the shape of all the variables in the problem line.

Comment: @hpaulj ok, i will edit the question

Comment: What about the shape of G?

Comment: `G` is the weights matrix of each classifier for each sample. So it is `n_samples` x `n_classifiers`

Comment: I was going to trace those shapes through your code to get the shape of `P3d[row, col, pred-1]`, but then realized I couldn't (with any confidence) match `n_samples`, `n_classifies` with 150, 6 or 3.  It just got too confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing fully reproducible code, it's a bit hard to tell what `G = self._compute_g(X)` is doing. However, the returned value `G` seems to have shape `(150, 6)`, not `(150, 3)` as expected. Hence you get the shape mismatch error.

I would suggest some careful inspection of `G` to confirm that `self._compute_g(X)` is doing what you expect.

As a side note, judicious use of `assert` to confirm the shape of various arrays can help catch many of these sort of errors. i.e. `assert G.shape == (M, N)`

Comment: Thanks! It was not clear that the problem came from `G` shape for me.